# How to delete all elements in one command for a tk treectrl

Tags: tk-toolkit

I want to delete all elements in a tk  treectrl  , I find commands like pathName item delete , but not sure how can it be done with single command

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer pathName item delete all
http://tktreectrl.sourceforge.net/treectrl.html#91